# How to add dynamic property in angularjs object

Tags: angularjs

I have object

```
$scope.postData = {
  'pmu.messages.message': $scope.upd.message,
  'pmu.received.id': $scope.upd.atomByReceivedBy.id,
};
```

and in scope there is `$scope.ImageList` which contains image path array

```
[
  { img: 'a.jpg', smallimg: 'b.jpg', smpath: 'c.jpg' },
  { img: 'a1.jpg', smallimg: 'b1.jpg', smpath: 'c1.jpg' },
];
```

I want to add these array value to $scope.postData field property value
as

```
$scope.postData = {
   'pmu.messages.message': $scope.upd.message,
   'pmu.received.id': $scope.upd.atomByReceivedBy.id,
   'pmu.image[0].img':
   'pmu.image[0].smallimg':
   'pmu.image[0].smimg':
   'pmu.image[1].img':
   'pmu.image[1].smallimg':
   'pmu.image[1].smimg':
}
```

How to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

Iterate `$scope.ImageList` and use Bracket Notation to create properties.

Here in the example, I have used just one property

```
$scope.ImageList.forEach(function(element, index){
    $scope.postData['pmu.image[' + index +'].img'] = element.img;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can iterate the array with `Array.forEach`, and then extract the key & value of each image using `Object.entries`.

```js
$scope = {
  upd: {
    message: '',
    atomByReceivedBy: {
      id: ''
    }
  },
  ImageList: [{
      img: 'a.jpg',
      smallimg: 'b.jpg',
      smpath: 'c.jpg'
    },
    {
      img: 'a1.jpg',
      smallimg: 'b1.jpg',
      smpath: 'c1.jpg'
    },
  ]
}

$scope.postData = {
  'pmu.messages.message': $scope.upd.message,
  'pmu.received.id': $scope.upd.atomByReceivedBy.id,
};

$scope.ImageList.forEach((img, index) => {
  Object.entries(img).forEach(([key, value]) => {
    $scope.postData[`pmu.image[${index}].${key}`] = value;
  });
});

console.log($scope.postData);
```

Comment: Working properly